# Real life examples of functional programming spirits applied in imperative languages?

Tags: functional-programming

Most people say that even functional programming is less likely to land you a job, you can become a better imperative/OO programmer by learning it.

For me, it's mostly about writing "non member non friend" functions that have no side effects. But I couldn't come up with more examples where functional programming can be *effectively* applied in imperative languages, because working around languages' lack of features is often too cumbersome.

So what are some more (*specific*) examples/techniques that you actually applied in non-functional languages that were inspired by functional programming?

#### Another of my own experience

This one is quite abstract, but due to the lack of "objects" in most FP languages, the culture there tends favor rigorous data structure design. Usually, in OOP languages, because stuffing an extra variable in a class is too easy, things tend to go mess up rather quickly. Though the same could be done using OCaml's and Haskell's record syntax, that kind of approach somehow feels out of place in FP.

Comment: To some extent it depends on the language.  Some languages make FP techniques *so* verbose that most of the patterns simply don't translate without the code becoming a mess (see: Java).   Whereas in Javascript and C#, for example, there are many FP idioms that are completely helpful and applicable.

Comment: http://jparsec.codehaus.org/ can be a nice and ideomatic example.

Comment: @Kirk Woll, Java is not that bad, see http://functionaljava.org/

Comment: @SK-logic, when the language we are talking about does not even sport functions (or methods) as first-class citizens of the language (that can be passed around) then indeed that language is not well-suited to accomodate functional idioms.  For example, try passing a callback to a method in Java.  If you are using an anonymous implementation of an interface, then you'll see the obscene amount of boiler-plate code to which I refer.   Now, that being said, Java [*will* eventually have such facilities](http://javac.info/).  Until then, though, it's quite crude.

Answer (score 2):

### Data Transformation

In my experience thinking on how to solve a problem functionally makes you think more about what data gets **transformed** to what - and not what **state** needs to be changed in order to keep the damn thing running...

Thinking of **problems as transformations** makes them appear different all by itself - which leads to different and most likely more elegant solutions.

**Update**: In c++ there is the <functional> header, and [std::transform](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/transform.html) in <algorithm>.

Comment: Before C++1x (with lambdas) is widespread, `<functional>` and `<algorithm>` will introduce an extreme amount of noise into the surround code (e.g., create a local `struct` just to define `operator()`). Last time I checked, compilers support for C++1x are still not _quite_ ready for heavy duty use.

Comment: @kizzx2 that is correct :) - [boost::lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/lambda) tend to be noisy too...

Answer (score 0):

Most Ruby Enumerable methods are inspired by Higher Order Functions from Functional programming

Answer (score 0):

The new-ish JavaScript array functions, filter, map, every, some, reduce, and reduceRight, are functional-inspired.

Answer (score 0):

Functional Java was already mentioned in the comments, but there is also some functional-ish stuff in [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). See the [org.apache.commons.collections.functors](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/p/org.apache.commons.collections.functors) package.